# ASP.NET Gridview Checkbox column - Onclick and jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

On click of checkbox, I need to retrieve immediate parent span's class value:

The checkbox column is defined in an ItemTemplate as:

```
 <asp:CheckBox CssClass='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  Checked='<%# Eval("IsSelected") %>' 
                                        Text="" runat="server"  onclick="CartItemCheckClicked()" />
```

The JS function is defined as:

```
function CartItemCheckClicked() {
        alert($(this).parent().attr('class')); //Undefined
        //alert($(this).attr('id')); //Undefined
    }
```

Ouput Sample HTML

```
<span class="283"><input type="checkbox" onclick="CartItemCheckClicked();" checked="checked" name="grvShoppingCart$ctl02$ctl00" id="grvShoppingCart_ctl00_0"></span>
```

But the result is always **'undefined'**. How do I access the checkbox or parent span?

Comment: Is everything else resolving?  Are you getting what you expect when you do `alert($(this).attr('class'))`?  I'm guessing that `this` is not the `this` you're looking for.

Comment: yea.. when debugged in firefox 'this' = Window webpage.aspx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass  checkbox to click function:

```
onclick="CartItemCheckClicked(this);"
```

And in js file than:

```
function CartItemCheckClicked(chk) {
        alert($(chk).parent().attr('class')); 
    }
```

Comment: also since your using jQuery you can use it to bind the click event intead, then you dont have worry about passing the arg at all. i.e. `$('input').click(function(){ alert($(chk).parent().attr('class')); })`